# Single dynamic modal/JS in spread-sheet like overview (instead one for each cell)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a spread-sheet like overview with hundreds of cells in there and each cell is a link that opens a modal with form to adjust the contents of the cell (and some additional data, so inline edit is not preferable).

I'm not very familiar with JS but what the page (html with php db) currently does, is creating hundreds of JS Scripts (for each cell 1) but I don't believe thats the correct way, it most definitely is not improving the performance of the page.

What I need, is that each link call on teh same modal, but with different content to show. But how can I pass on some variables or something?(eg. some GET variables or so).

I now create a unique ID for each cell to call on the modal with the pre-filled content (so there are hundreds of forms in this page), but better would be a single modal that receives information I can use to communicate with the DB and fetch the content the moment the modal is opened.

```
<a href="#42aa04334a02670b6cf0fbe7b4be3e37" role="button" data-toggle="modal">0,00</a>
<div id="42aa04334a02670b6cf0fbe7b4be3e37" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">xx modal content that is created related to the cell</div>
```

ps. I used bootstrap 2, including jQuery etc. but I don't think that matters for my question

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use single modal. Just apply class, use `data-target=".className"` to call modal, use `data-*` to pass formula.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cell").click(function() {
    $(".modal .modal-body").html("<input type='text' value='" + $(this).data('formula') + "'/>");
  });
});
```

```css
.cell {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="cell" data-formula="x-y/z" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">1</div>
<div class="cell" data-formula="x-a/z" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">2</div>
<div class="cell" data-formula="x*b*cz" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">3</div>
<div class="cell" data-formula="c*d/0.5" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".modal">4</div>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit cell formula</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Justinas! This definately the direction I need to go to :) One aditional question:
If I want to pass on a ID and catch this with PHP how would I do this (for example "data-id="123" must end up in <?php $id=123; ?>) or is this not possible because its already parsed?

Comment: When opening the modal, it should call on an Ajax script to get the correct content, and in order to do that, I need to have some variables in PHP.

Comment: @ThomasD. To pass php variable to `data-*` do `data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"`. Than use Ajax to mare post/get request to server (I will not explain that, since there is full of examples in internet).